# OpenMPI 1.4.3 mpirun hostfile error

Tags: c, mpi, centos5, openmpi

I am trying to run a simple MPI program on 4 nodes. I am using OpenMPI 1.4.3 running on Centos 5.5. When I submit the MPIRUN Command with the hostfile/machinefile, I get no output, receive a blank screen. Hence, *I have to kill the job.* .

I use the following run command: : mpirun --hostfile hostfile -np 4 new46

```
 OUTPUT ON KILLING JOB:
 mpirun: killing job...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process that caused 
  that situation.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mpirun was unable to cleanly terminate the daemons on the nodes shown
   below. Additional manual cleanup may be required - please refer to
   the "orte-clean" tool for assistance.
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    myocyte46 - daemon did not report back when launched
    myocyte47 - daemon did not report back when launched
    myocyte49 - daemon did not report back when launched
```

Here is the MPI program I am trying to execute on 4 nodes

```
   **************************

   if (my_rank != 0)
   {
    sprintf(message, "Greetings from the process %d!", my_rank);
    dest = 0;
    MPI_Send(message, strlen(message)+1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
   else
   {
   for (source = 1;source < p; source++)
   {
    MPI_Recv(message, 100, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("%s\n", message);
   }

   ****************************
```

My hostfile looks like this:

```
   [amohan@myocyte48 ~]$ cat hostfile
   myocyte46
   myocyte47
   myocyte48
   myocyte49
   *******************************
```

I ran the above MPI program independently on each of the nodes and it compiled and ran just fine. I have this issue of "*Daemon did not report back when launched*" when I use the hostfile. I am trying to figure out what could be the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these lines

```
myocyte46 - daemon did not report back when launched
```

are pretty clear -- you're having trouble either launching the mpi daemons or communicating with them afterwards.    So you need to start looking at networking.   Can you ssh without password into these nodes?  Can you ssh back?   Leaving aside the MPI program, can you

```
mpirun -np 4 hostname
```

and get anything?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was able to ssh back and forth between nodes. It looks like the admin had left the firewall running and turning that down seems to work. Also, I noted on some of the linux forums that they suggested adding . /etc/bashrc as the first item on the bashrc profile.